# Python and threading: Why does "large" list entity get lost when accessing from other method?

Tags: python, multithreading

A large entity (list) is created in one method (`foo`) and bound to `self.result`.
The attempt to access this entity in a second method (`transmit`) fails starting at a certain size (something between 150,000 and 155,000 characters in the list). Printing (`print self.result)` from inside `transmit` leaves me with None.
I guess this is important: `self.foo` is directly called in a separate thread.
Please help. How do I get such "large" entity from a separate thread back into the main thread without such limitation?

```
...

    def apply(self):
        self.get_data()
        self.start_foo_thread()

    def start_foo_thread(self):
        self.foo_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.foo)
        self.foo_thread.daemon = True
        self.progressbar.start()
        self.foo_thread.start()
        self.master.after(20, self.check_foo_thread)

    def check_foo_thread(self):
        if self.foo_thread.is_alive():
            self.master.after(20, self.check_foo_thread)
        else:
            self.progressbar.stop()

    def foo(self): 
        s = self.stringinput
        n = self.numberinput
        list = multiply_str_into_list(s, n)
        self.result = list_to_text(list)
        print self.result # output is not None 

    def transmit(self):
        print self.result # output is None for more than about 155,000 characters in the list
        return self.result

def multiply_str_into_list(string, n): #takes a string and multiplies it by n and writes into list
    n_string = []
    for i in range(0,n):
        n_string.append(string)
    return n_string

def list_to_text(list): #takes a list as input and joins it into str with each list item on a new line
    a = '\n'.join(list)
    return a
```

Comment: Although as far as I can tell it's not the cause of your problem here, generally you shouldn't name things `list` and `string` because those are already used for built-in types or modules and doing so can cause unintended side-effects, as well as make it hard for others to read. It can also make debugging harder.

Comment: @martineau: +1 for that hint

Answer (score 0):

You don't really provide enough information to reproduce the problem, let alone debug it, but my guess is that at some point, you are doing something like this:

```
self.result = self.result.append(x)
```

Since `.append()` modifies the list in place, and returns `None`, this will clobber the reference to the list. It needn't be `.append()` either -- all of the methods that mutate lists return `None`.

As to why it is happening only at a certain size, perhaps you have some code like the above that is triggered only at a certain size, or else it is a red herring.

Comment: @kindall: yes i use .append() at some point (i have edited my question). I still don't get the connection to some certain size when it happens...

Comment: Python names are pointers to objects -- the name is being changed to point at `None` instead of the list. Python does not magically change pointers to `list`s to point to `None` when the lists get too big. *Something in your code* is doing that. I suggested a way it might be happening, but there could be other ways. Find it and fix it.

Comment: @kindall: i have given more code now, maybe you can spot what i messed up?

Comment: @solarisman: How does the rest of your code determine that the `self.foo_thread` has finished, so it's OK to now call `transmit()`? `self.result` shouldn't be accessed by any other threads until that time.

Comment: @solarisman: `self.request` could get changed to `None` if the object it is part of (some sort of TKinter Dialog I suspect) has gone out of scope since it was created and `apply()` got called. Not sure why that would only happen when the number in the list exceeds a certain size, though.

Comment: @martineau: i see that point. so now in my case, either way: progressbar works but this issue above or progressbar doesn't show up...i think i forget about multi threading for now